# Raspberry Pi Camera Module undetectable by common applications

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi4, v4l2, v4l2loopback, picamera

I bought a 5 mp camera module available at Amazon for my raspberry pi 4 2 gb model. Then I configured it for use and tested it with `raspistill` and `raspivid`, it is working as expected. But since it is a module connected to the CSI port and not a USB camera its is not detectable by some common applications. For eg.:- OBS(From Pi-Apps), Zoom(From PI-Apps, Pi-Kiss and its web portal).

What I tried ? --

1. Virtual camera through OBS. I was able to install OBS but I wasn't able to compile
   its plugin for virtual camera and camera module. It had numerous errors.
2. IP camera adapter :- Idea was to stream the camera feed on local web and then convert the feed to a virtual camera. Yes, there are many such applications but all are available only for windows/Mac and not for Linux. Even the few, which are available doesn't support Raspberry pi's architecture.

Is there any workaround or a trick for make the module work like a normal camera ?

P.S.:- If you are wondering why the question is on Stackoverflow,then I feel this is a software related question and Stackoverflow is the best for that ;).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into `libcamera`?

https://www.arducam.com/docs/cameras-for-raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-libcamera-guide/

That might not be the best, straight-forward answer you're looking for, but I recently did some work with a PiCam and found libcamera to work wonders.  I used it on a fairly low level and didn't try to point it to additional programs, but perhaps you can find something useful in there!  Good luck.

Comment: Can u pls elaborate. I checked the link and tried the virtual camera node which can be accessed by pyhton. But Zoom doesn't care to recognize it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).